# Do AWS messaging services support STOMP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, stomp

Do AWS [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) and [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) support [STOMP protocol](https://stomp.github.io/)?

I have tried googling it. I went through several forums but I am not sure yet.

Answer (score 4):

No. Amazon SNS and Amazon SQS have their own API.

STOMP would need to support those services (rather than vice versa), but it appears that STOMP does not support SNS nor SQS.

Comment: STOMP is not a service or system... it's a wire protocol for interacting with queues and topics.  I once wrote a proof-of-concept STOMP gateway for SQS using Mojolicious, and it worked nicely... so it is indirectly possible for clients that speak native STOMP to interact with SQS or SNS, but you'd need to have a custom gateway to do the protocol translation. We decided not to go with the gateway concept, and instead we rewrote our services to speak to the native SQS/SNS APIs.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, John, STOMP is a protocol. It shouldn't implement any service provider or implementation. SNS or SQS can choose to implement it but they didn't. However, for STOMP one can use Amazon MQ (source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/welcome.html).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, AWS have the another message queue service for the Apache ActiveMQ that does support JMS, NMS, AMQP, STOMP, MQTT, WebSocket and called [Amazon MQ](https://aws.amazon.com/en/amazon-mq)